# Problem With updmap-sys

Tags: texlive, updating

I ran the TeX Live 2012 update this morning on my 64-bit Kubuntu 12.04 linux system (`tlmgr update --all`) and received the following error:

```
tlmgr: package log updated at /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
running mtxrun --generate ...
done running mtxrun --generate.
running updmap-sys ...

updmap-sys failed (status 1), output:
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
dvips output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap"
pdftex output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap"
dvipdfmx output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap"
pxdvi output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pxdvi/updmap"

ERROR:  The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
        ${PKGNAME}.map (in /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)

        Did you run mktexlsr?

        You can disable non-existent map entries using the option
          --syncwithtrees.


tlmgr: exiting unsuccessfully (status 1).
```

Running `updmap-sys --syncwithtrees` gives the following:

```
david@dd:~$ updmap-sys --syncwithtrees
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
Missing map files found, disabling
        ${PKGNAME}.map (in /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
in /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
Do you really want to continue (y/N)? y
answer =y=
Creating new config file /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
Use of uninitialized value in subroutine entry at /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux/updmap line 1332,  line 1.
Can't use string ("") as a subroutine ref while "strict refs" in use at /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux/updmap line 1332,  line 1.
```

I'm lost at this point. Can anyone at TUG help?

Answer (score 9):

This seems to be a recently reported problem, and I suspect there will be a more permanent fix distributed, (as confirmed by Norbert's answer) but for the moment, edit the file (you will probably need to use an editor that allows you to authenticate to save, or invoke your editor with `sudo`.)

```
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
```

In it you will find a line

```
${PKGNAME}.map
```

As egreg notes in the comments, this is an error in the `bguq`, so you can change this line to

```
bguq.map
```

and save the file.  Then run:

```
sudo updmap-sys
```

And you should be fine.

Comment: The culprit is `bguq`, for which the corresponding `bguq.tlpsrc` file says `execute addMap ${PKGNAME}.map`. Changing the entry in `updmap.cfg` to `bguq.map` and running `sudo updmap-sys` solves the problem in the immediate.

Comment: Thanks ! I had the same problem with MacTeX 2012 and your fix does the trick.

Comment: I owe you a beer, Alan. `:)`

Answer (score 6):

Fixed already in today's update. For those who had the same problem, just wait until the respective CTAN mirror is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and simply changed the repository source, which then deinstalled some packages I didn't care about and then the updating worked fine.
So just change your source.

Comment: Thanks, Hurwicz!  I tried Alan's suggestion, and that seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that `--syncwithtrees` is not recommended for Debian type distributions (including Kubuntu). I had a similar problem and traced it to a missing `tipa.map` file which was resolved with `apt-get install tipa`.